# Create SPRING BATCH JOBS in RUN TIME and Execute them

Tags: runtime, spring-batch, jobs, one-to-one, file-processing

I have a requirement where i will take input CSV files from one folder, process them (DB lookup and validation) one after one and generate new output file for each input file.  I need to choose the input files at RUN TIME based on the DB query on user object which will tell what are the qualified files (like out of 400 files in folder - 350 may be qualified to process and I need to generate 350 output files).  I want to use SpringBatch and want to create one JOB for one File. Any reference or sample code to **create JOBs at RUN TIME and Execute them?**

Comment: Can anyone help and provide suggestions?